# PySpark map datetime to DoW

Tags: datetime, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to map a column 'eventtimestamp' to its day of week with the following function:

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction as udf



def toWeekDay(x):
    v = int(datetime.strptime(str(x),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%w'))
    if v == 0:
        v = 6
    else:
        v = v-1
    return calendar.day_name[v]
```

and for my `df` trying to create a new column `dow` with UDF.

```
udf_toWeekDay = udf(lambda x: toWeekDay(x), StringType())
df = df.withColumn("dow",udf_toWeekDay('eventtimestamp'))
```

Yet, I'm getting error I do not understand at all. Firstly, it was complaining for inserting datetime.datetime into `strptime` instead of string. So I parsed to str  and now I don't have a clue what's wrong.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-9040214714346906648.py", line 267, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-9040214714346906648.py", line 260, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 429, in take
    return self.limit(num).collect()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 391, in collect
    port = self._jdf.collectToPython()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o6250.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1107.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1107.0 (TID 63757, ip-172-31-27-113.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 819): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Thanks a lot for clues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use date_format to get dayofweek,

```
df = df.withColumn("dow",date_format(df['eventtimestamp'],'EEEE'))
```

Comment: Hi,. thanks, it works well! But do you have any idea why my version doesn't work?

Comment: Just for future reference, the format parameters are here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thanks for reference. BTW, your function works fine. I am not able to reproduce the error.

Comment: that's really strange, I still can't seem to be able to make it work. Do you reckon I should maybe post it somewhere as an issue? Maybe it has something to do with the format of my `df`?

Comment: if you could provide the input data, we can check.